# How to instantiate images upon user click in windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I have small Image for a circle and I want to make the following:

Whenever some place on my form is clicked, I want to add a new instance of that circle in that place if there is no other circle there already.

I was thinking about a list of Circles and when that click happens i check the list to see if none of its circles is overlapping before adding the new one but I don't have any experience with forms so i don't know what would be the best approach for that.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes, I instantiated a new PictureBox and used Controls.Add(new_box);

I didn't explain right, I have a png with the circle image, I'm not trying to draw it.

Comment: Well that makes no big difference; you still can use my code for the checks, just change it a little: Leave out the whole Paint event and do you Add(new_box) in the `if clause`..!

Answer (score 1):

You can build up a `GraphicsPath` and check if the clicked point is inside any of its parts with the `IsVisible` method.

This code also builds up a list of the points and to draws the image to each of it in the Paint event. If you let the `GraphicsPath` do the drawing you uncomment  the `DrawPath` line and delete these //** list related lines.

```
GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath();
List<Point> PL = new List<Point>();    //**

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int diameter = 22;  // put in the size of your circle
    Size s = new Size(diameter, diameter);

    if (!GP.IsVisible(e.Location))
    {
        Point middle = new Point(e.X - diameter / 2, e.Y - diameter / 2);
        GP.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(middle, s));
        PL.Add(middle);    //**
    }

    this.Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Firebrick, GP);
    Image img = new Bitmap("D:\\circle22.png");  //**
    foreach(Point pt in PL) e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, pt);  //**
    img.Dispose();   //**
}
```